# How to parse CSV file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata

Now I have a .csv file, with a column of time, such that "20140203 00:00:03.132", how can I drop the seconds part(":03.132") efficiently? The data amount is huge, and I tried preprocess the data using sed but it was too slow!

I am now trying parse the .csv file in pandas. Is there anyway I could handle that efficiently? Methods other than pandas is also welcomed!

Comment: If you don't have a cluster to perform the operation on, then anything you try will be slow considering it'll all be done on one machine

Comment: pandas might not be the fastest way... afaik, it just uses the standard csv module, with extra processing including attempting to coerce everything to data types; string operations are faster, so just using the iterating csv reader would be faster. how much data are we talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a handy library for parsing timestamps: [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime
x = '20140203 00:00:03.132'
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print datetime.datetime.strftime(timestamp, '%Y%m%d %H:%M')  # 20140203 00:00
```

Or since it's a bit slow for a huge amount of data, you can split from the right on the first `:` and then take the first element of the resulting list:

```
print x.rsplit(':', 1)[0]  # 20140203 00:00
```

Comment: I tried so but it was slow considering the huge amount of data.

Comment: @xxx222 Fair enough. You can split the string on the last `:` like this `print x.rsplit(':', 1)[0]` which will yield the same result, and this will be a fast operation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look that the `date_parser` parameter to [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv). Something along the lines of this should work:

```
import dateutil
from pandas import read_csv

def my_date_parser(seq):
    return [dateutil.parser.parse(s[:14]) for s in seq]

csv = read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=[3], date_parser=my_date_parser)
```

You will probably need to also supply parameter `parse_dates` to nail down the column(s) containing the date strings, e.g. above specifies column 3 as a date column.