# How to parse out a dataframe from .csv file. which contains header detail rows using Python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a file I am trying to extract values from to create a data frame. I have tried a regex approach to create lists from the file, but data format(Header/H and Detail/D) as below is giving me inconsistent row counts when I input the resulting lists into a data frame. I think the issue is that some records have 1 detail (D) row while others have more than 1 (D) row. Could you suggest another approach? I was thinking of trying to create a dictionary object where each H row would be the key and each D row would be the value, using a for loop of some kind.

The file format is as below:

H,     INV34801, 20200201, 09:18:55,     IN,          5
D,     INV34801,            0053,      1.00,     IN, 20200201, 09:18:55,
H,     INV34802, 20200201, 10:12:35,     IN,          5
D,     INV34802,     D22345433DU,     -1.00,     IN, 20200201, 10:12:35,
D,     INV34802,                ,      1.00,     IN, 20200201, 10:12:35,

This the code I have been trying:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    import itertools
    #First I extract the date that each sale took place. 
    lst1= [line for line in re.findall(('[IN, ]\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d'), contents)]
    #Now I remove every alternate date to remove the duplicate date I can confirm seeing that the                                 
    #date column has the same number of rows as the Invoice Number column
    lst1=lst1[1::2]
    #Now I extract the invoice number
    lst2= [line for line in re.findall("INV\w*",contents)]
    # Now I extract the product codes
    lst3=[line for line in         
    re.findall(('\s\s\s\s\s\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w|\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s|\n
    \s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\d\d\d\d|\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\d\d\d\d\d\d'),contents)]
    #Now I extract the Quantity Sold 
    lst4=[line for line in re.findall(('\s\s\s\s\s\s\d\.\d\d'),contents)]
    #then I create a column from the list of Invoice numbers
    df=pd.DataFrame([lst1,lst2,lst3,lst4])
    df =df.transpose()
    df.columns=['Date','Invoice_Number','Product_Code','Quantity']
    print(df)
    '''
```

The output structure I get is correct but the quantity and product codes arent lined up to the correct invoice numbers.

Dataframe below:

```
    Date Invoice_Number      Product_Code    Quantity
    0      20200201       INV34801                          1.00
    1      20200201       INV34802                          1.00
    2      20200201       INV34803                          1.00
    3      20200201       INV34804                          1.00
    4      20200201       INV34805                          8.00
```

I'd appreciate your kind advice.

Comment: what kind of regex is this `\s\s\s\s\s\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w|\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s|\n
    \s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\d\d\d\d|\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\d\d\d\d\d\d` you can use`\s{m,n}\w{m,n}`etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse CSV file using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248240/how-to-parse-csv-file-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
regex = r"[H,D] (?P<invoice_nr>[^,]*)(, (?P<date>[^,]*)[\s\S]*?(?P<quantity>-?\d+\.00), IN)[\s\S]*?(\n|$)"
```

I have made you an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/SDgUHR/1), not sure if this helps, but it should give you some pointers on regex